# creating a 2 column table in python

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I want to create a multivariate 2 dimensional standard normal distribution. This is essentially just a combination of 2 1d standard normal distributions.

```
m1 = rand.normal(0,1,500)
m2 = rand.normal(0,1,500)
```

How do I combine these arrays so that I get a 500x2 table in a concise way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, simply pass the `size` parameter:

```
>>> m = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(500, 2))
>>> m.shape
(500, 2)
>>> m.mean(axis=0)
array([-0.02394296,  0.0684164 ])
>>> m.std(axis=0)
array([ 1.04018539,  0.95281971])
```

[I'm assuming that your `rand` is the `numpy.random` module.]

See also the [random.multivariate_normal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html) function if you want to specify a particular covariance.